# AOP: more calls to a pointcut than I expected

Tags: java, aspectj, aop

I'm trying AspectJ and in making a counter I've encountered something I don't understand. Here's the code:

```
aspect testaAssociacao perthis(execucoesReceita()){

  pointcut execucoesReceita() : execution(* Receita.*(..));

  int x;

    //constructor
    public testaAssociacao() { x = 0; }
    after(): execucoesReceita(){
      x = x+1;
      System.out.println("x = "+x); 
    }
}
```

in the main() there is:

```
  Receita r1 = new Receita("bolo1");
  Receita r2 = new Receita("bolo2");

  r1.adicionaIngrediente(new Ingrediente("FARINHA", 3));
  r1.adicionaIngrediente(new Ingrediente("leite", 1));
  r1.adicionaIngrediente(new Ingrediente("FARINHA", 2));
  r1.adicionaIngrediente(new Ingrediente("leite", 3));
```

in this situation the exit shows:

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 1
x = 2
```

if I remove the `perthis()` declaration so it wont separate by object Receita the exit comes like this:

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
```

How is possible that the counter arrived at 5 if there are just 4 operations?
Does it consider the main() function, or runs execution at another moment?

Comment: are there any static initializer methods in Receita?

Comment: No there aren't, Receita right now does basically nothing, just the standard constructor and the function adicionaIngrediente.

Comment: Is the main() function within Receita.java ?

Comment: Oh, so clever, Suraj. That's probably it.

Comment: you could have `new Exception().printStackTrace();` to track where the advice is executed

Comment: Could you please close or delete this question? It is still listed as unanswered.